# Error: Expected session attribute 'form'

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

When I sent this post request I got this error:

```
 org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute
 'form' 
 at   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel
```

What're the causes (possibilities) for this kind of exception? I Am using Spring MVC to develop this web application.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new/form",params ="mode",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String newForm(@ModelAttribute("form") ApplicationForm form,

                               BindingResult bindingResult,
                               @RequestParam String mode,
                               Model model,
                               SessionStatus sessionStatus) {

    return showSearchForm(model);
}
```

Comment: Code snippet would be handy !

Comment: Your `@ModelAttribute("form")` ? or Session attribute ?

Comment: psoted the controller ! , yes am using Session Attribute @ItachiUchiha

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your view (HTML, JSP, JSF, whatever) as well?

Comment: @mthmulders actually I can't the JSP is too large, The content is private so I cannot trim it to make it for bublic. But let see what are the possibilities that makes spring rise this exception !

Answer (score 2):

try using these annotations at the beginning of the class

> @SessionAttributes({"form"})
>
> @Controller

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by Spring MVC unable to find "form" in your session to be populated to your model. Typically this happen the very first time the user made request. Often the pattern used to handle this scenario is to check the existence of the model attribute, and create a new one if it doesn't exist

```
if(!model.containsAttribute("form")) model.addAttribute("form", new Form());
```